# replacing lines of a text file with text of another file using sed or awk

Tags: database, sed, awk

I have a text file e.g File1.txt and I want to replace its few lines with new lines available in another text file e.g File2.txt. The format of File1.txt is as below It has pointers start and end.

```
START

line 1
line 2
line 3 
line 4
line 5

END
```

I want to change line 1 to line 5 with the lines available in File2.txt. The number of lines are not equal in File1.txt and File2.txt. File2.txt may have more or less lines as in File1.txt.

I need input from someone. Thanking in anticipation

Comment: Do you want preserve the empty lines before line 1 and after line 5? Will there be any empty lines between line 1 and line 5?

Answer (score 1):

If the parts of *File1.txt* that you want to preserve are fixed,
you only need to print the second file and include that parts:

```
printf 'BEGIN\n\n%s\n\nEND\n' "$(<File2.txt)"
```

IF that's not the case (substitute START/END with the patterns 
that match the parts that you want to preserve):

```
awk 'NR == FNR {
  f2 = f2 ? f2 RS $0 : $0
  next
  }
/START|END/ || !NF {
  print; next  
  }
NF && !c++ { 
  print f2 
  }' File2.txt File1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This GNU sed one liner might work:

```
sed -re '/^START/,/^END/{/^START/{p;r File2.txt' -e '};/^END/p;d}' File1.txt
```

This inserts `File2.txt` between `START` and `END` but doesn't preserve empty lines after `line 1` and before `line 2`

This tries to preserve empty lines:

```
sed -re '/^START/,/^END/{//!{/^$/{p;d};x;/./{x;d};x;h;r File2.txt' -e ';d};x;s/.*//;x}' File1.txt
```